# Android Crash activity killed, librealm-jni

Tags: android, crash, realm, native-code

I'm getting a strange crash when trying to open a new detail fragment from within a list fragment (adapter). No real crash is logged (exception). The only clue lies within logcat and seems to indicate this issue is related to Realm?

```
11-30 13:16:27.377 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 
11-30 13:16:27.377 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/angler/angler:7.0/NBD91K/3318877:user/release-keys'
11-30 13:16:27.377 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
11-30 13:16:27.377 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
11-30 13:16:27.378 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG: pid: 9686, tid: 9686, name: mycompany.myapp  >>> com.mycompany.myapp <<<
11-30 13:16:27.378 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x248
11-30 13:16:27.378 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000000000  x2   0000000000000238  x3   0000000000000000
11-30 13:16:27.378 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000007463352290  x6   0000007471657880  x7   0000000000000000
11-30 13:16:27.378 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000000  x9   0000000000000000  x10  0000000000430000  x11  0000000000000000
11-30 13:16:27.378 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000000c00000000  x13  0000000000000001  x14  000000006fbe4138  x15  003b9aca00000000
11-30 13:16:27.378 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000007fe9bdc270  x17  000000748c4fb2e8  x18  951554862bff8710  x19  0000000000000000
11-30 13:16:27.378 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000000000000000  x21  0000000000000000  x22  0000007461f54000  x23  0000000012fbee80
11-30 13:16:27.378 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000000000000000  x25  000000006f72b500  x26  000000006f734978  x27  000000006f86cbb0
11-30 13:16:27.378 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG:     x28  000000006f7e2ec0  x29  0000007fe9bdc220  x30  00000074631e6d98
11-30 13:16:27.378 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007fe9bdc220  pc   00000074631e6adc  pstate 0000000020000000
11-30 13:16:27.382 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
11-30 13:16:27.382 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000014cadc  /data/app/be.mycompany.myapp-2/lib/arm64/librealm-jni.so
11-30 13:16:27.382 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000000000014cd94  /data/app/be.mycompany.myapp-2/lib/arm64/librealm-jni.so
11-30 13:16:27.382 11340-11340/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00000000000448d0  /data/data/be.mycompany.myapp/cache/slice-io.realm-realm-android-library-2.0.1_43b803c8f080077d4082d4af3ca386c2fa9e07e6-classes.dex (offset 0x70000)
```

**EDIT:**
Realm version 2.0.1

**EDIT2:**

I did activate the logging in my App class. Keep getting strange realm errors, switching to the latest version (2.2.1) and now my app also closes on logging in.

```
    Build fingerprint: 'google/angler/angler:7.1.1/NMF26F/3425388:user/release-keys'
12-16 18:18:25.010 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
12-16 18:18:25.011 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
12-16 18:18:25.011 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG: pid: 18085, tid: 18299, name: RxIoScheduler-3  >>> com.mycompany.myapp <<<
12-16 18:18:25.011 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
12-16 18:18:25.012 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI FindClass called with pending exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace()' on a null object reference'
12-16 18:18:25.012 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000000000000000  x1   000000000000477b  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000008
12-16 18:18:25.012 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     x4   000000000000002f  x5   8080000000000000  x6   0000000000008080  x7   feff666e6b61686b
12-16 18:18:25.012 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000083  x9   ffffffffffffffdf  x10  0000000000000000  x11  0000000000000001
12-16 18:18:25.012 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000000000000030  x13  ffffffffffffffff  x14  ffffffffff000000  x15  ffffffffffffffff
12-16 18:18:25.012 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000007c83a57ee0  x17  0000007c83a01aac  x18  0000000000000000  x19  0000007c59f494f8
12-16 18:18:25.012 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000000000000006  x21  0000007c59f49450  x22  000000000000000b  x23  0000007c82ffe000
12-16 18:18:25.012 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000007c82f4c49b  x25  0000007c82f86198  x26  0000007c59f47db1  x27  0000007c82ffc740
12-16 18:18:25.012 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     x28  000000000000158a  x29  0000007c59f47c90  x30  0000007c839feed8
12-16 18:18:25.012 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007c59f47c70  pc   0000007c83a01ab4  pstate 0000000060000000
12-16 18:18:25.022 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
12-16 18:18:25.022 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000006bab4  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
12-16 18:18:25.022 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0000000000068ed4  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+64)
12-16 18:18:25.022 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0000000000023f58  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+24)
12-16 18:18:25.022 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000000000001c810  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+52)
12-16 18:18:25.022 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000000000433ad4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+464)
12-16 18:18:25.022 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00000000000e5a7c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+1592)
12-16 18:18:25.022 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 00000000002f080c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+2200)
12-16 18:18:25.022 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 00000000002f0af4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortVEPKcS2_St9__va_list+124)
12-16 18:18:25.022 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0000000000102718  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck6AbortFEPKcz+156)
12-16 18:18:25.022 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0000000000102128  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck11CheckThreadEP7_JNIEnv+536)
12-16 18:18:25.022 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00000000000ffc68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+1124)
12-16 18:18:25.022 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 00000000000f1538  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI9FindClassEP7_JNIEnvPKc+612)
12-16 18:18:25.022 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 000000000009a1b4  /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-1/lib/arm64/librealm-jni.so
12-16 18:18:25.023 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 000000000009add0  /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-1/lib/arm64/librealm-jni.so
12-16 18:18:25.023 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 0000000000046e50  /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-1/lib/arm64/librealm-jni.so (Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeBeginTransaction+376)
12-16 18:18:25.023 18406-18406/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 00000000000517a4  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/cache/slice-io.realm-realm-android-library-2.2.1_897a13e69e94b5f98f9b622f6ffc80cefe2c8bf2-classes.dex (offset 0x71000)
```

Comment: What version of Realm are you using?

Comment: Realm version 2.0.1

Comment: You can get a better log by adding RealmLog.add(new AndroidLogger(LogLevel.VERBOSE)) in your application class. Can you post the output of that?

Comment: Ok, check my edit ;)

Comment: @Jordy have you found any solution for this?